# Hessian for Matrix Factorization objective

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

Consider the objective for Matrix Factorization:
$$f(W,H) = \frac 12 \|X - WH\|_F^2 \to \min,$$
where $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ is given and $W \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$, $H \in \mathbb R^{k \times m}$ are required to find.

Two questions:

1. Is there a simple representation of $\nabla^2 f$? It should be a matrix of size $(nk + km) \times (nk + km)$, which stores $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial W_{ij} \partial W_{kl}}$, $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial W_{ij} \partial H_{kl}}$, $\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial H_{ij} \partial H_{kl}}$ for all $i,j,k,l$.

For gradients, there are simple formulae:
\begin{align*}
\nabla f_W &= -X H^\top + W H H^\top \\
\nabla f_H &= -W^\top X + W^\top W H,
\end{align*}
which are not hard to obtain by expanding the Frobenius norm using the inner product. For Hessian, I don't know one: I tried to do this, it's doable, but intermediate results are a complete mess.

2. (What I really need) Is there a simple way to compute the smallest eigenvalue of $\nabla^2 f$? In the first place, I don't want to build $\nabla^2 f$ if possible, since it's a bit too large, and I'm not sure I'll be able to find the smallest eigenvalue quickly. At the very least, is there a way to work with a smaller matrix instead? It's also guaranteed that all elements of $X,W,H$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

For ease of typing, define
$$A = (WH-X) \quad\implies\quad dA = W\,dH+dW\,H$$
and write the gradients more concisely as
$$G_w = AH^T, \qquad G_h = W^TA$$
First, calculate the differentials of the gradients.
$$\eqalign{
dG_w &= A\,dH^T + dA\,H^T \\
  &= A\,dH^T + W\,dH\,H^T + dW\,HH^T \\
dG_h &= W^T\,dA+dW^T\,A \\
  &= W^TW\,dH + W^TdW\,H + dW^T\,A \\
}$$
Next, apply the [Kronecer-vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) operation to these differential expressions.
$$\eqalign{
dg_w &= {\rm vec}(dG_w) \\
 &= \Big[(I_k\otimes A)C_h + (H\otimes W)\Big]dh + \Big[HH^T\otimes I_n\Big]dw \\
 &= \Big[M_{wh}\Big]dh + \Big[M_{ww}\Big]dw \\
\\
dg_h &= {\rm vec}(dG_h) \\
 &= \Big[I_m\otimes W^TW\Big]dh
  + \Big[(H^T\otimes W^T)+(A^T\otimes I_k)C_w\Big]dw \\
 &= \Big[M_{hh}\Big]dh + \Big[M_{hw}\Big]dw \\
}$$
where $(C_h,C_w)$ are the [commutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product, and $\big(M_{hh},\,M_{hw},\,M_{wh},\,M_{ww}\big)$ can be identified as the desired Hessian matrices.

Finally, you wished to assemble them into a single (block) matrix
$$
M = \left[\begin{matrix}
M_{ww} &M_{wh} \\
M_{hw} &M_{hh} \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
It's worth pointing out that $M_{hw}^T=M_{wh}\,$ so the Hessian is symmetric (as it should be).

Comment: Thank you! Where it's better to read about Kronecker products, commutation matrices and stuff?

Comment: The standard text is probably _Matrix Differential Calculus_ by Magnus and Neudecker.

Answer (score 1):

From your formula, we can see that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{ij}} = -X^i (H^j)^T + W^i H (H^j)^T,\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial H_{ij}} = -(W_i)^TX_j + W_i^T W (H_j),
$$
where $M^i$ denotes the $i$th row of $M$ and $M_i$ the $i$th column. Thus, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_{kl}\partial W_{ij}} = \delta_{ik} H^l (H^j)^T.
$$
The mixed partial is a bit trickier. We find that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial H_{kl}\partial W_{ij}} = 
-\delta_{jl}X_{ij} + W_{ik}H_{lj} + \delta_{jk}W^iH_l,
$$
Finally, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial H_{kl}\partial H_{ij}} = \delta_{jl} W_i^TW_k.
$$

---

With that, we can build $M = \nabla_W^2 f$: we have
$$
M = \sum_{i,k = 1}^n\sum_{j,l = 1}^k (e_j \otimes e_i)(e_l \otimes e_k)^T\delta_{ik} H^l (H^j)^T
\\ = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j,l = 1}^k (e_j \otimes e_i)(e_l^T \otimes e_i^T) H^l (H^j)^T
\\ = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j,l = 1}^k (e_j \otimes e_i)(e_l^T \otimes e_i^T) e_l^TH H^T e_j
\\ = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j,l = 1}^k (e_je_l^TH H^T e_je_l^T) \otimes (e_ie_i^T)
\\ = \sum_{j,l = 1}^k ([H H^T]_{lj}e_je_l^T) \otimes I_n
\\ = (HH^T) \otimes I_n.
$$
I suspect that similar computations can be made for the remaining Hessian blocks.

Comment: Thanks! I finally should go and learn tensors.

Comment: @Dmitry Those $\otimes$'s are Kronecker products; everything here is matrices